# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.gdata.client.contacts.ContactsService

Tags: java, google-contacts-api, servlet-3.0

Good day.

I've developed from serveral time a Tomcat's java servlet called after the the Google Authentication that must to creare a new entry on Google Contact.
I have a my application on Google Console that allow it.
In a past time this function running without problem.
I've tried it now and an error occurs when I try to instance the ContactsService class.
The code is ContactsService service = new ContactsService("ImmobiWeb");
The exception occurs is 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.gdata.client.contacts.ContactsService

ImmobiWeb is the name of my Google application in Google Console.
The version of Google Contact Java API is gdata-contacts-3.0 and in this jar file the class is present.

How can I resolve my problem?

Best regards and good work.

Stefano Errani

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/java_client_lib) article about the gdata client. In this case you need download the gdata-client library (jar) and place inside WEB-INF/classes directory in your war file

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if 'gdata-contacts-3.0.jar' is in the WEB-INF folder of your web application?

Answer (score 0):

gdata-contacts-3.0.jar is in the lib directory (WEF-INF/lib) of my application.